# Vagrant unable to provision from a machine despite copy/pasting the path

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant-provision

I'm having trouble starting Vagrant with Virtual box. The code I enter into a blank project folder on the command line is:

```
vagrant init tsawler/wafs; vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

In response I get the following message:

---

C:\Users\Owner\PhpstormProjects\modernphptut>vagrant init tsawler/wafs; vagrant up --provider virtualbox
An invalid option was specified. The help for this command
is available below.
Usage: vagrant init [options] [name [url]]

Options:

```
    --box-version VERSION        Version of the box to add
-f, --force                      Overwrite existing Vagrantfile
-m, --minimal                    Create minimal Vagrantfile (no help comments)
    --output FILE                Output path for the box. '-' for stdout
-h, --help                       Print this help
```

---

I am copying the command line text exactly as shown on this page: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/tsawler/boxes/wafs

This is my first attempt using Vagrant/virtual machines. Anyone know why it's not working? I installed Vagrant and Virtualbox just today on my Windows 10 machine so I have the most recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a multiple line command and this

```
vagrant init tsawler/wafs; vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

works well in linux or mac os but does not work for windows.

For windows you should run as

```
vagrant init tsawler/wafs & vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

Or you can also run the commands one by one

```
C:\Users\Owner\PhpstormProjects\modernphptut>vagrant init tsawler/wafs
.....
C:\Users\Owner\PhpstormProjects\modernphptut>vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```